# Problem in returning values from javascript function to flex

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, transliteration

In the attached flex code, I am trying to call a javascript function in its HTML wrapper.
The example is also live at :
http://www.cse.epicenterlabs.com/mbm/ajax_api.html
The problem I am facing is, that I have to click the button twice
to get the desired output. Seems like there is some delay in setting the
"output" variable. How could I get the output from the javascript function in one click?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:TextArea x="209" y="139" height="245" width="318"  id="text1" fontSize="28"/>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
                import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
    import flash.external.*;

     public function callWrapper():void {
        var s:String;
        if (ExternalInterface.available) {
           var wrapperFunction:String = "initialize";
           s = ExternalInterface.call(wrapperFunction,text1.text);
           text1.text = s;

        } else {
           s = "Wrapper not available";
        }
        trace(s); 
     }

                ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Button x="92" y="118" label="Transliterate" click="callWrapper()"/>
</mx:Application>
```

HTML Wrapper :

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html lang="en">

<!-- 
Smart developers always View Source. 

This application was built using Adobe Flex, an open source framework
for building rich Internet applications that get delivered via the
Flash Player or to desktops via Adobe AIR. 

Learn more about Flex at http://flex.org 
// -->

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!--  BEGIN Browser History required section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css" />
<!--  END Browser History required section -->

<title></title>
<script src="AC_OETags.js" language="javascript"></script>

<!--  BEGIN Browser History required section -->
<script src="history/history.js" language="javascript"></script>
<!--  END Browser History required section -->

<style>
body { margin: 0px; overflow:hidden }
</style>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Globals
// Major version of Flash required
var requiredMajorVersion = 9;
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredMinorVersion = 0;
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredRevision = 28;
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -->
</script>
</head>

<body scroll="no">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("language", "1");

        var output;
    function initialize(input) {
      google.language.transliterate([input], "en", "hi", function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          if (result.transliterations && result.transliterations.length > 0 &&
            result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords.length > 0) {
            output = result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords[0];
          }
        }
      });
    return output;
    }
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Version check for the Flash Player that has the ability to start Player Product Install (6.0r65)
var hasProductInstall = DetectFlashVer(6, 0, 65);

// Version check based upon the values defined in globals
var hasRequestedVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);

if ( hasProductInstall && !hasRequestedVersion ) {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THE FOLLOWING FOUR LINES
    // Location visited after installation is complete if installation is required
    var MMPlayerType = (isIE == true) ? "ActiveX" : "PlugIn";
    var MMredirectURL = window.location;
    document.title = document.title.slice(0, 47) + " - Flash Player Installation";
    var MMdoctitle = document.title;

    AC_FL_RunContent(
        "src", "playerProductInstall",
        "FlashVars", "MMredirectURL="+MMredirectURL+'&MMplayerType='+MMPlayerType+'&MMdoctitle='+MMdoctitle+"",
        "width", "100%",
        "height", "100%",
        "align", "middle",
        "id", "ajax_api",
        "quality", "high",
        "bgcolor", "#869ca7",
        "name", "ajax_api",
        "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
        "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
        "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    );
} else if (hasRequestedVersion) {
    // if we've detected an acceptable version
    // embed the Flash Content SWF when all tests are passed
    AC_FL_RunContent(
            "src", "ajax_api",
            "width", "100%",
            "height", "100%",
            "align", "middle",
            "id", "ajax_api",
            "quality", "high",
            "bgcolor", "#869ca7",
            "name", "ajax_api",
            "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
            "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
            "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    );
  } else {  // flash is too old or we can't detect the plugin
    var alternateContent = 'Alternate HTML content should be placed here. '
    + 'This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. '
    + '<a href=http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/>Get Flash</a>';
    document.write(alternateContent);  // insert non-flash content
  }
// -->
</script>
<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
            id="ajax_api" width="100%" height="100%"
            codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
            <param name="movie" value="ajax_api.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <embed src="ajax_api.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
                width="100%" height="100%" name="ajax_api" align="middle"
                play="true"
                loop="false"
                quality="high"
                allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            </embed>
    </object>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `google.language.transliterate` is not a synchronous operation. Your `initialize` function returns even before `google.language.transliterate` has finished running (which is why you are attaching a callback function to run after it is done).

You need to callback an actionscript function after transliterate is done. Explore ExternalInterface.addCallback() to add an actionscript function callable from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `google.language.transliterate` in the JavaScript code is asynchronous, that is why it seems like you have to press the button twice. The anonymous function that is passed as the fourth argument doesn't run until some data has been loaded.

Perhaps you should show some kind of loading indicator just before calling `google.language.transliterate` and then hiding it in the handler? That way you would see when it's loading data.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a html file using the script and use that inside Flex HTML component.

Example:

```
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:HTML id="html"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        location="{serverIp}/Translit.html"/>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, it worked.
I am attaching the working code here :

Flex code :    (**ajax_api.mxml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
        <mx:TextArea x="209" y="139" height="245" width="318"  id="text1" fontSize="28"/>
        <mx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import flash.external.*;

         public function callWrapper():void {
            var s:String;
            if (ExternalInterface.available) {
       ExternalInterface.addCallback("g", g);
               var wrapperFunction:String = "initialize";
               ExternalInterface.call(wrapperFunction,text1.text);

            } else {
               s = "Wrapper not available";
            }
            trace(s); 
         }
         public function g(str:String):void
         {
            text1.text = str;
         }

                ]]>
        </mx:Script>
        <mx:Button x="75" y="50" label="Enter some text and click this button to see the transliteration output" click="callWrapper()" height="37"/>
    </mx:Application>
```

HTML Wrapper :

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html lang="en">

<!-- 
Smart developers always View Source. 

This application was built using Adobe Flex, an open source framework
for building rich Internet applications that get delivered via the
Flash Player or to desktops via Adobe AIR. 

Learn more about Flex at http://flex.org 
// -->

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!--  BEGIN Browser History required section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css" />
<!--  END Browser History required section -->

<title>ajax_api</title>
<script src="AC_OETags.js" language="javascript"></script>

<!--  BEGIN Browser History required section -->
<script src="history/history.js" language="javascript"></script>
<!--  END Browser History required section -->

<style>
body { margin: 0px; overflow:hidden }
</style>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Globals
// Major version of Flash required
var requiredMajorVersion = 9;
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredMinorVersion = 0;
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredRevision = 28;
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -->
</script>
</head>

<body scroll="no">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("language", "1");
function thisMovie(movieName)
{

    if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1)
    {
        alert("microsoft");
        return window[movieName];
    }
    else
    {
        return document[movieName];
    }
}

function initialize(input) {
      google.language.transliterate([input], "en", "hi", function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          var container = document.getElementById("transliteration");
          if (result.transliterations && result.transliterations.length > 0 &&
            result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords.length > 0) {
            output = result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords[0];
        thisMovie("ajax_api").g(output);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Version check for the Flash Player that has the ability to start Player Product Install (6.0r65)
var hasProductInstall = DetectFlashVer(6, 0, 65);

// Version check based upon the values defined in globals
var hasRequestedVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);

if ( hasProductInstall && !hasRequestedVersion ) {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THE FOLLOWING FOUR LINES
    // Location visited after installation is complete if installation is required
    var MMPlayerType = (isIE == true) ? "ActiveX" : "PlugIn";
    var MMredirectURL = window.location;
    document.title = document.title.slice(0, 47) + " - Flash Player Installation";
    var MMdoctitle = document.title;

    AC_FL_RunContent(
        "src", "playerProductInstall",
        "FlashVars", "MMredirectURL="+MMredirectURL+'&MMplayerType='+MMPlayerType+'&MMdoctitle='+MMdoctitle+"",
        "width", "100%",
        "height", "100%",
        "align", "middle",
        "id", "ajax_api",
        "quality", "high",
        "bgcolor", "#869ca7",
        "name", "ajax_api",
        "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
        "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
        "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    );
} else if (hasRequestedVersion) {
    // if we've detected an acceptable version
    // embed the Flash Content SWF when all tests are passed
    AC_FL_RunContent(
            "src", "ajax_api",
            "width", "100%",
            "height", "100%",
            "align", "middle",
            "id", "ajax_api",
            "quality", "high",
            "bgcolor", "#869ca7",
            "name", "ajax_api",
            "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
            "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
            "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    );
  } else {  // flash is too old or we can't detect the plugin
    var alternateContent = 'Alternate HTML content should be placed here. '
    + 'This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. '
    + '<a href=http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/>Get Flash</a>';
    document.write(alternateContent);  // insert non-flash content
  }
// -->
</script>
<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
            id="ajax_api" width="100%" height="100%"
            codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
            <param name="movie" value="ajax_api.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <embed src="ajax_api.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
                width="100%" height="100%" name="ajax_api" align="middle"
                play="true"
                loop="false"
                quality="high"
                allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            </embed>
    </object>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```